# Clojure macro that writes try blocks

Tags: clojure, macros, try-catch

## Problem

I am trying to define a macro using Clojure that works similarly to try in java
It should be able to have a binding form, for example [variable value], that can bind to an instance of a closable.

## Example in Java

```
try (Socket s = new Socket()) {
s.accept();
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

In this code, the socket 's' is automatically closed as if there is explicitly a finally clause

```
finally {
if (s != null) s.close();
}
```

## Attempted solution

```
;I am defining my macro. It can either take one argument(expression) or can take two arguments(expression and a vector with two elements(a variable and value)
;expression is a form expression and should be able to be evaluated
(defmacro safe 
    ; if a vector and also an expression is passed into the macro
    [s NewS expression]
    ;I am defining my try block, and unquoting it with a ' so that the try block is not executed within the macro
    `(try   
        ;I am letting the variable(NewS) be equal to the value(s)
        (let [s NewS]
        ;I am trying the expression to see if it is valid and printing the exception if there is one
        (try 
            ~expression (catch Exception e (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e))))
        )
        ;I am checking if my value is an instance of a java closeable
        (instance? java.util.Closeable s)
        ;I am catching the exception from the let statement if there is one
        (catch Exception e (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e)))
    )
    ;if only an expression is passed into the macro
    [expression]
    `(try
        ~expression (catch Exception e (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e)))
    )
)
```

## Example input and output

```
user> (def v (safe (/ 1 0)))
user> v
#<ArithmeticException java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero>
user> (def v (safe (/ 10 2)))
user> v
5
user> (def v (safe [s (FileReader. (File. "file.txt"))] (.read s)))
user> v
105 ; first byte of file file.txt
user> (def v (safe [s (FileReader. (File. "missing-file"))] (. s read)))
user> v
#<FileNotFoundException java.io.FileNotFoundException:
missing-file (No such file or directory)>
```

## Error message

When I put these example inputs into my main function I get a compiler excpetion that I don't understand.

```
CompilerException clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/safe, compiling:(/private/var/folders/6f/q7lhngtn45q_xpzd_24gjp2h0000gn/T/form-init2350735096437822603.clj:1:8)
```

I don't know what I can adjust in this macro but I cannot get it to not return errors.

## Update

This solution almost works

```
(defmacro safe
    ([[s NewS] expression]
    `(try  
        (let [~s ~NewS] ~expression) (catch Exception e# (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e#)))
    ))
    ([expression]
    `(try
        ~expression (catch Exception e# (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e#)))
    ))
)
```

But the following test fails

(defn -main
    "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
    [& args]
    (import java.io.FileReader java.io.File)
    (def v (safe [s (FileReader. (File. "file.txt"))] (.read s)))
    (println v)
)

```
user$ lein run
caught exception: file.txt (No such file or directory)
user$ cat file.txt 
teast
```

Comment: I think you could use [`with-open`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-open) for this.

Comment: I don't really understand what my main flaws are. Even when I use with open I get similar errors

`(defmacro safe [& [s newS] expression]
    (if s
        `(let [~s ~newS]))
    `(with-open ~newS & ~expression)
    )

(defn -main
    [& args]
    (def v (safe (/ 1 0)))
) `

Comment: Have yoy checked what `macroexpand` gives for your macro? You have the code formatted poorly here, so it's hard to read.

Comment: Also, Clojure uses semicolons for comments, not plain hashes.

Comment: Also, think about what `s` and `newS` are for your divide by 0 example.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I posted an update with a new attempted solution. I don't know what more I can fix in the question and don't know what the errors mean exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-closing behavior is already solved by `with-open` macro. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3785). Here's a formulation that (I think) does what you ask.

```
(defmacro safe
  ([body]
   `(try ~body
      (catch Exception e#
        (str "caught exception: " e#))))
  ([bindings & body]
   `(try
      (with-open ~bindings
        ~@body)
      (catch Exception e#
        (str "caught exception: " e#)))))
```

Example usage:

```
(safe (/ 1 nil))
;;=> "caught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException"

(safe [s (clojure.java.io/reader "file.txt")]
  (prn (.read s)))
;;=> "caught exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (No such file or directory)"

(spit "file.txt" "contents here")
(safe [s (clojure.java.io/reader "file.txt")]
  (.read s))
;;=> 99
```

## However

1. Returning a string on failure is confusing because what if the *expected* value is also a string? Then how do you know if your evaluation succeeded or failed? Maybe you just want to print/log the exception and return nil? (In that case consider replacing `str` with `println` in your `catch` block.)
2. Having two arities of `safe` (one which takes only one body form and another that takes binding(s) to be `close`d *and* body forms) entangles concerns that should arguably be separated. `with-open` already exists and we shouldn't reinvent it when we can reuse it.

This version of `safe` takes any number of forms instead of only one, so it's now more flexible.

```
(defmacro safe
  [& body]
  `(try ~@body
     (catch Exception e#
       (println "caught exception:" (.getMessage e#)))))
```

And we can easily use `with-open` *within* `safe` to get your desired behavior:

```
(safe
 (prn (/ 1 2)) ;; prints 1/2
 (with-open [s (clojure.java.io/reader "not_a_file.txt")]
   (.read s))) ;; fails, prints exception

(safe
 (with-open [s (clojure.java.io/reader "file.txt")]
   (char (.read s)))) ;; returns the first char from file we `spit` above
;;=> \c
```